# Gapless audio in video

Tags: audio, adobe, production

It's possible to produce mp4/webm videos without sound that loop seamlessly, but if you add sound to the video with matching length it adds a noticeable stutter at the end, even if the audio is slightly shorter than the video.

Is it possible to produce a web friendly (mp4/webm) video with sound that is gapless?

I use Adobe products and ffmpeg to produce my videos, if that matters.

Answer (score 1):

This can happen if the GOP structure is unclosed at the end of the video. If you can assure that your video ends with an I frame, and that the audio is exactly the same length as the video, you stand a much better chance of getting a smooth recycle. Sorry, I don't know how to force that using ffmpeg.

Comment: Thanks for the info, helped me learn a lot about how encoding works. I was able to figure out how to set the keyframe interval and make sure the last frame was a keyframe but it didn't change anything. I have a WebM video that loops seamlessly with ffplay but not in Chrome/Firefox, it seems like they just don't support gapless video/audio playback.